# How to use unpkg url-join.js as <script src=...> import?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to use `urlJoin` in my project. I've imported the library/script using `<script>` tag as the HTML is generated by `Django`.

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/url-join@5.0.0/lib/url-join.js"></script>
```

The problem is that I can't use `urlJoin` function - the console says:

```
urlJoin
VM609:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: urlJoin is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:1
```

The function is defined like this:

```
export default function urlJoin() {
  var input;

  if (typeof arguments[0] === 'object') {
    input = arguments[0];
  } else {
    input = [].slice.call(arguments);
  }

  return normalize(input);
}
```

Do you know how to use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file is an ES6 module. See [JavaScript modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules) on MDN.

You need to:

- Mark the script where you use `urlJoin` as a module
- `import` it into that script
- **Not** have a separate `<script>` element to load `urlJoin`.

Thus:

```html
<script type="module">
  import urlJoin from "https://unpkg.com/url-join@5.0.0/lib/url-join.js"; 
  const foo = urlJoin("some", "args"); 
  console.log(foo);
</script>
```